# Write text filename as date in c#

Tags: c#

So I've looked around for the answer and I'm just getting started with using c# so its probably simple, but I've got a block of code

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "TextDocuments|*.txt", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
            {
                sw.WriteLineAsync(txtMessage.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Your entry has been saved successfully!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

What I want to know is how I'm meant to preset the filename as a date in this code?

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Set your SaveFileDialog's FileName property to the filename you wish...if it is to be a date then format the date as a filename. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileName)

Comment: if you want to force the filename then remove the SaveFileDialog and use the streamwriter with your desired file name, if the user can only pick the folder use a FolderBrowserDialog instead, if not, will be confusing for the user if they change the defaultname and the program just ignore it

Answer (score 1):

assign the current DateTime to `DefaultFileName` property on save file dialog instance

```
sfd.DefaultFileName=DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

or

```
sfd.FileName=DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: So im not sure if ive done it correctly but ive editted the code to this

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString()))

but its still not working, the rest of the code is still the same as the original post im just wondering what else i should've done?

Comment: here's an example from MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileName)

Answer (score 0):

```
    string logPath = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt", DateTime.Now); 
        Console.WriteLine("Path: " + logPath);

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"./" + logPath, true))
            {
                file.Write(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", DateTime.Now, log, Environment.NewLine, bankLog));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Logs inserted to file");
```